# Why do most Multi-Process apps have same name

Tags: windows, design-patterns, multiprocessing

Does anyone know why (if there is a reason at all, e.g. shared memory) applications that have multiple processes (usually per tab) all share the same name?

E.g.

- chrome.exe
- edge.exe
- vscode.exe

Why don't they have a parent process e.g. `chrome-window.exe` and `chrome-tab.exe`.

Is there any benefit of having them share the same executable other than deployment?

Some reason that come to mind:

1. Easier to Share Memory?
2. Easier Inter Process Communication?
3. Less UAC?

Comment: Because it's always the same executable that is running (spawned from the master process)

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html

Comment: @gargkshitiz I understand why they have "Multiple processes" render, compiler, etc, but why the same executable (.exe), why not have `chrome-render.exe` `chrome-compiler.exe`.